# Flask Restplus : Sending DateTime as a parameter

Tags: rest, flask, flask-restful, flask-restplus

```
@ns.param('startTime', 'The task identifier', type=datetime)
def get(self):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('startTime', type = datetime)
```

I want to send datetime as an argument for the GET request but it is giving me error. I tried to look in the documentation but it was not that helpful. Can somebody help me with this.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: TypeError: <class 'datetime.datetime'> is not JSON serializable